# Are there any open source web font servers?

Tags: font-face, webfonts, google-webfonts, typekit

I am looking for something similar to the [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts/), [Fontdeck](http://fontdeck.com/), or [Typekit](https://typekit.com/) services.

Answer (score 0):

There was *Fontue*—a Rack-based open source web font server. It was initially built for kernest.com but it seems it is no longer available.

Since I needed one myself, I ended up writing my own web font server—[Mjau](https://github.com/noll/mjau). It is fully functional and I've been using it for quite some time in production without any problems.